# String express evaluation matching

Tags: java, regex, string, scala, expression

It is possible to do expression evolution comparison using string in java.

Say if I have list of rules :

1. create AND [table OR view] AND as AND select
2. [insert OR delete] AND table

Assume that **OR group is always within** the square brackets []

I would like do a pattern match (similar to the database GRANT permissions)

I want to block the following commands :

- create table something as select * from test => should be blocked (from condition 1)
- create view something as select ***** => should be blocked (from condition 1)
- insert into table => should be blocked (from condition 2)
- delete table => should be blocked (from condition 2)
- select * from test => allowed as it doesn't match the rule pattern

In general I want to build something similar to block/grant permission on database queries.

Is there any Java library for expression evaluation matching in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the below two simple regex

```
1.create (table|view).*?as select .*
2.(insert|delete)?.*table
```

You can test it in https://regex101.com/ and let me know if you find any issue.

Comment: thanks for reply,I'm not looking for regex as I want end users to configure this using simple expression something like twitter search api operators but only AND and OR https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/rules-and-filtering/overview/standard-operators